# Using replaceAll on a String for replacing \\s by \t not working. Bug?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, replaceall

I created this code for replacing spaces by tab:

```
String r="Tabular este texto".replaceAll("\\s","\t");
System.out.println(r);
```

But when I try to run it, what I get is this:

```
Tabular este    texto
```

The first space between "Tabular" and "este" seems to be invisible to NetBeans as it didnt get replaced by tab. But the weirdest thing is, if I write anything else instead of that sentence, like "OLOL OLOL OLOL", it gonna work perfectly:

```
OLOL    OLOL    OLOL
```

So, what is happening here?

Comment: How many characters wide is your tab? (I'm going to guess 4.)

Comment: `\t` != fixed number of spaces

Comment: It did get replaced by tab. Why don't you examine the actual character at `r.charAt(7)` to see if it is a tab?

Comment: David, i tried what you just said and it really returns a tab, but while running my code it isnt visually a tab. Maybe there is something to do with what Louis said I guess. Thanks all anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess that your console displays tabs by aligning to a certain position, not as equivalent to a specific number of spaces.  Note that the `este` and the `OLOL` in your example line up vertically...